# Converting xml that contains polygon to yolo

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I want to convert a polygon annotation through voclabel.py to yolo format, but there is always error because of this file convert rectangle shape only

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need to convert from pascal voc to yolo but the xml files contains polygon shapes not rectangle shapes so the python code that convert from voc to yolo cant read the xml file i dont know how to make it read polygons not only rectangle , I am using VOC_label.py

Comment: most of image annotation tools provide the polygon shape for annotation and export the xml file for voc dataset but when trying to convert from pascal voc to yolo it doesn't work because the python code read rectangle shapes by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: https://github.com/ssaru/convert2Yolo , it boils down to this class:

```py
class VOC:
    """
    Handler Class for VOC PASCAL Format
    """

    def xml_indent(self, elem, level=0):
        i = "\n" + level * "\t"
        if len(elem):
            if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
                elem.text = i + "\t"
            if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
                elem.tail = i
            for elem in elem:
                self.xml_indent(elem, level + 1)
            if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
                elem.tail = i
        else:
            if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
                elem.tail = i

    def generate(self, data):
        try:

            xml_list = {}

            progress_length = len(data)
            progress_cnt = 0
            printProgressBar(0, progress_length, prefix='\nVOC Generate:'.ljust(15), suffix='Complete', length=40)

            for key in data:
                element = data[key]

                xml_annotation = Element("annotation")

                xml_size = Element("size")
                xml_width = Element("width")
                xml_width.text = element["size"]["width"]
                xml_size.append(xml_width)

                xml_height = Element("height")
                xml_height.text = element["size"]["height"]
                xml_size.append(xml_height)

                xml_depth = Element("depth")
                xml_depth.text = element["size"]["depth"]
                xml_size.append(xml_depth)

                xml_annotation.append(xml_size)

                xml_segmented = Element("segmented")
                xml_segmented.text = "0"

                xml_annotation.append(xml_segmented)

                if int(element["objects"]["num_obj"]) < 1:
                    return False, "number of Object less than 1"

                for i in range(0, int(element["objects"]["num_obj"])):

                    xml_object = Element("object")
                    obj_name = Element("name")
                    obj_name.text = element["objects"][str(i)]["name"]
                    xml_object.append(obj_name)

                    obj_pose = Element("pose")
                    obj_pose.text = "Unspecified"
                    xml_object.append(obj_pose)

                    obj_truncated = Element("truncated")
                    obj_truncated.text = "0"
                    xml_object.append(obj_truncated)

                    obj_difficult = Element("difficult")
                    obj_difficult.text = "0"
                    xml_object.append(obj_difficult)

                    xml_bndbox = Element("bndbox")

                    obj_xmin = Element("xmin")
                    obj_xmin.text = element["objects"][str(i)]["bndbox"]["xmin"]
                    xml_bndbox.append(obj_xmin)

                    obj_ymin = Element("ymin")
                    obj_ymin.text = element["objects"][str(i)]["bndbox"]["ymin"]
                    xml_bndbox.append(obj_ymin)

                    obj_xmax = Element("xmax")
                    obj_xmax.text = element["objects"][str(i)]["bndbox"]["xmax"]
                    xml_bndbox.append(obj_xmax)

                    obj_ymax = Element("ymax")
                    obj_ymax.text = element["objects"][str(i)]["bndbox"]["ymax"]
                    xml_bndbox.append(obj_ymax)
                    xml_object.append(xml_bndbox)

                    xml_annotation.append(xml_object)

                self.xml_indent(xml_annotation)

                xml_list[key.split(".")[0]] = xml_annotation

                printProgressBar(progress_cnt + 1, progress_length, prefix='VOC Generate:'.ljust(15), suffix='Complete', length=40)
                progress_cnt += 1

            return True, xml_list

        except Exception as e:

            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]

            msg = "ERROR : {}, moreInfo : {}\t{}\t{}".format(e, exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)

            return False, msg

    @staticmethod
    def save(xml_list, path):

        try:
            path = os.path.abspath(path)

            progress_length = len(xml_list)
            progress_cnt = 0
            printProgressBar(0, progress_length, prefix='\nVOC Save:'.ljust(10), suffix='Complete', length=40)

            for key in xml_list:
                xml = xml_list[key]
                filepath = os.path.join(path, "".join([key, ".xml"]))
                ElementTree(xml).write(filepath)

                printProgressBar(progress_cnt + 1, progress_length, prefix='VOC Save:'.ljust(15), suffix='Complete', length=40)
                progress_cnt += 1

            return True, None

        except Exception as e:

            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]

            msg = "ERROR : {}, moreInfo : {}\t{}\t{}".format(e, exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)

            return False, msg

    @staticmethod
    def parse(path):
        try:

            (dir_path, dir_names, filenames) = next(os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)))

            data = {}
            progress_length = len(filenames)
            progress_cnt = 0
            printProgressBar(0, progress_length, prefix='\nVOC Parsing:'.ljust(15), suffix='Complete', length=40)
            for filename in filenames:

                xml = open(os.path.join(dir_path, filename), "r")

                tree = Et.parse(xml)
                root = tree.getroot()

                xml_size = root.find("size")
                size = {
                    "width": xml_size.find("width").text,
                    "height": xml_size.find("height").text,
                    "depth": xml_size.find("depth").text

                }

                objects = root.findall("object")
                if len(objects) == 0:
                    return False, "number object zero"

                obj = {
                    "num_obj": len(objects)
                }

                obj_index = 0
                for _object in objects:

                    tmp = {
                        "name": _object.find("name").text
                    }

                    xml_bndbox = _object.find("bndbox")
                    bndbox = {
                        "xmin": float(xml_bndbox.find("xmin").text),
                        "ymin": float(xml_bndbox.find("ymin").text),
                        "xmax": float(xml_bndbox.find("xmax").text),
                        "ymax": float(xml_bndbox.find("ymax").text)
                    }
                    tmp["bndbox"] = bndbox
                    obj[str(obj_index)] = tmp

                    obj_index += 1

                annotation = {
                    "size": size,
                    "objects": obj
                }

                data[root.find("filename").text.split(".")[0]] = annotation

                printProgressBar(progress_cnt + 1, progress_length, prefix='VOC Parsing:'.ljust(15), suffix='Complete', length=40)
                progress_cnt += 1

            return True, data

        except Exception as e:

            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]

            msg = "ERROR : {}, moreInfo : {}\t{}\t{}".format(e, exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)

            return False, msg
```

And focus on the `parse` function, that is what you need to convert the labels properly.

Comment: I was trying to use what you have told me to focus on parsing but this error always come out when i use python example.py --datasets VOC --img_path /home/tarek/darknet/convert2Yolo-master/ --label/home/tarek/darknet/convert2Yolo-master/ --convert_output_path ./ --img_type ".jpg" --manipast_path ./ --cls_list_file /home/tarek/darknet/convert2Yolo-master/label.names

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 11, in <module>
    from Format import VOC, COCO, UDACITY, KITTI, YOLO
  File "/home/tarek/darknet/convert2Yolo-master/Format.py", line 71
    print('\r%s|%s| %s%% (%s/%s)  %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, iteration, total, suffix), end = '\r')
                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I was trying to parse the xml file through the code you shared up

Comment: Did you copy all the repo? Don't just copy the code, try to understand what it does, if you see those errors it's because you are not copying the entire repo and passing the correct paths of the dataset

Comment: I have copied the entire repo and it worked with normal rectangle annotation but when i enter the xml file which contains objects which is annotated with polygon shapes it cant convert to yolo format @bpinaya

Comment: <polygon>
<username>anonymous</username>
<pt>
<x>105</x>
<y>72</y>
</pt>
<pt>
<x>133</x>
<y>62</y>
</pt>
<pt>
<x>151</x>
<y>64</y>
</pt>
<pt>
<x>163</x>
<y>71</y>
</pt>
<pt>
<x>170</x>
<y>78</y>
</pt>
<pt>
<x>172</x>
<y>85</y>
</pt>
<pt>
<x>173</x>
<y>108</y>
</pt>
<pt>
<x>159</x>
<y>119</y>
</pt>
<pt>
<x>136</x><y>125</y></pt><pt><x>116</x><y>124</y></pt><pt><x>99</x><y>109</y></pt><pt><x>96</x><y>100</y></pt><pt><x>100</x><y>83</y></pt></polygon></object>

Comment: This is how a polygon looks like in an xml file its voc dataset and i have annotated the polygon shape with labelme web annotation tool so basically there is no Xmin,Ymini,Xmax,Ymax @bpinaya

Comment: python3 example.py --datasets VOC --img_path /home/tarek/convert2Yolo/images/ --label /home/tarek/convert2Yolo/label/  --convert_output_path ~/YOLO/ --img_type ".jpg" --manipast_path ~/darknet/ --cls_list_file /home/tarek/darknet/scripts/VOCdevkit/VOC2007/names/labels.names

VOC Parsing Result : False, msg : ERROR : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find', moreInfo : <class 'AttributeError'> Format.py 239

Comment: That is the error that appears when i put the xml that have polygon shapes annotations @bpinaya

Comment: It might refer to this issue: https://github.com/ssaru/convert2Yolo/issues/13 seems that if there is no objects present the program crashes so try to patch that one

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the main question of parsing polygons and converting them to bounding boxes. I suggest unmarking it as accepted. @tarekaliabdallahteama